# Element slides in from left but hides in towards right

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-animations

When I click on the advanced filters button, the Filters slides in fro mthe left and the rest of the content is pushed towards the right. Similar to what happends here on clicking the Slidebar menu button - http://www.bootply.com/EOgJSIzPGS#

Here is the fiddle for my problem>> http://www.bootply.com/NpZDkzkP1u
[image]
But, when I click on the back button in the filters, the resulting animation is not the reverse of what just happened above. Instead the Filters section just disappears and the remaining section adjusts it's width and it appears as if it is sliding from the right end side
[image]

One more problem is this>>

```
.col-md-0 *{
  display: none;
}
```

I've to hide all the children, setting the parent width=0 is not hiding the elements at all

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes, here it is - http://www.bootply.com/NpZDkzkP1u